# How to follow automatic form submitting and redirection using nightmarejs (or casperjs/phantomjs)

Tags: web-crawler, phantomjs, nightmare

Using nightmarejs, I'd like follow several redirection and automatic form submitting, which is invoked by the page script. And want to get the last page.

For instance, the page content of `http://myexample/` like this:

```
<html><body>
<form action="http://somewhere/" method="post">
  <!-- some params -->
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('form').submit();
</script>
</body></html>
```

The script element of this page submits the form. And the post request to `http://somewhere/` is sent. And then `http://somewhere/` returns 302 response to `http://another/`.

To get the last page (`http://another/`), I tried nightmarejs code like this:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
new Nightmare()
    .goto('http://myexample/')
    .wait(1000)
    .url(function(url) {
        console.log(url);
    })
    .evaluate(function () {
        return window.location.href;
    }, function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .run();
```

I tried `url` and `evaluate` methods but I could not get last page.

Is there a way to support the case like this? The answer using casperjs or phantomjs are also welcome.

### UPDATE

I've tried PhanomJS and been able to follow redirects. But there was another problem that connection fails by `SSL Handshake failed` error. I've solved this to add `--ssl-protocol=any` option.

Comment: This will probably not possible with NightmareJS. Have you tried to increase the wait period? This should be easy with CasperJS, but there where problems with redirects under PhantomJS in the past.

Comment: I've tried PhansomJS and been able to follow redirects. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .wait(fn[, arg1, arg2,...]) method to follow a re-direct.

```
var loginUrl = '...';
var loggedInUrl = '...';
new Nightmare().goto(loginUrl)
  .type('#username', '')
  .type('#password', '')
  .click('#loginBtn')
  .wait(function () {
    return window.location.href === loggedInUrl;
  });
```

Alternatively, if there is some unique DOM element on the destination URL, you can use the .wait(selector) method.  Check out the documentation here: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare

Answer (score 0):

You can use the events described in the API to check when a redirect happens. If you use the `urlchanged` event, you get the new URL which you can use.

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#onevent-callback

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've solved this problem by adding `--ssl-protocol=any` option.